# Flutter: How to evenly space ListTiles in ListView

Tags: flutter

I am trying to evenly space my list tiles in my list view with the code below and it is not working.  The greater objective is to get both scroll and even distribution on rotation. Thanks for the help.

```
      Widget _buildBodyListView() {
        return new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Container(color: Colors.green,
            child: ListView(shrinkWrap: false,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                  title: Text('LATEST NEWS', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                  title: Text('MARKET NEWS ', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                  title: Text('MARKET REPORT', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
             ListTile(
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              title: Text('LATEST NEWS', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
            ListTile(
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              title: Text('MARKET NEWS ', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
            ListTile(
              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              title: Text('MARKET REPORT', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 82):

I recommend you use the [`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html) widget.
It has a property called the `separatorBuilder`. It return a `Widget`, *here a `SizedBox` of a particular height*, that will act as a separator.

Here is how you should do it:

```
ListView.separated(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 6,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: ListView(
        children: const <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('LATEST NEWS', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('MARKET NEWS ', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('MARKET REPORT', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('LATEST NEWS', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('MARKET NEWS ', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text('MARKET REPORT', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
    height: 10,
  )
);
```

Comment: Interesting approach

Comment: Happy to meet this answer. Solved my problem

Comment: I'm glad that is solved your problem.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

*"The ListView.builder constructor ... This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

The ListView.separated constructor takes ... This constructor is appropriate for list views with a fixed number of children.*
By reading this I wonder if Listview.separated is optimal for large (or infinite) number of children".

Answer (score 12):

Wrap your list tile with card.

```dart
Card(child : ListTile(title : Text('Your text',textAlign: TextAlign.center), dense : true), // ListTile ) // Card
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this one:

[ListView.separated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html)

It create a separation evenly between each item

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved it like this :

_hotels is my List,
I had an horizontal scroll view, and to keep the item space left and right equal, I have used the below code..
You can use the same for Vertical too with some minor changes...

```
ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: _hotels.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: index == _hotels.length - 1
                          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0)
                          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Container(
                ........
                ........
            ))
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

try itemExtent: Parameter of List View for me that worked fine

```
 ListView(
        itemExtent: 70.0,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children:[
       
         ]
      )
```

Comment: If you don't want to center elements, reomve "shrinkWrap: true"

Comment: How is this marked as correct?
[itemExtent](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/itemExtent.html) determines the height of the list items not the space between.

Answer (score 2):

In a scroll-able listview we (atleast myself) always want our content to begin at the top unlike a column whose evenly spaced feature allows widgets to occupy entire screen evenly. 
Following widget can provide an evenly distributed listview. You can call this `SampleWidget` in your Scaffold column.

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List tasksList = [
    Card( // cards provide nice margin
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('test1'),
      ),
    ),
    Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('test2'),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tasksList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return tasksList[index];
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and I couldn't find an ideal answer, but then I figure it out is that simply by using the `Padding` widget.

Appended this [Padding class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) link for your information

What you is simply wrap the Padding class with the ListTile class:

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: ListTile(
        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
        title: Text('LATEST NEWS', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
    )
);
```

If you want to customize the padding with top, right, bottom and left, replace the `EdgeInsets.all()` to `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(double left, double top, double right, double bottom)`. There are also other methods, check out [this documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html).

Comment: This will add a padding to all sides, even for the first and the last item. Sometimes this is okay but most of the time you only want a spacing BETWEEN the items

Answer (score 1):

He is asking how to "Evenly" Space, not just tossing some random pixels between them with sizedbox or padding. Case in point:

```
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(
          //width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 1, 1, 1),
          color: Colors.indigo,
          child: Row(
              //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // You can use following for LISTVIEW and comment out next line
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
                  // PLEASE REMEMBER THERE IS AN OVERFLOW HERE IF RESIZED TO SMALL SO PUT THIS IN A LISTVIEW
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: changeText, child: AutoSizeText('Previous', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: changeText, child: AutoSizeText('Play', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: changeText, child: AutoSizeText('Pause', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: changeText, child: AutoSizeText('Stop', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: changeText, child: AutoSizeText('Next', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ]
          )
        ),
      ),
```

Change from Row to ListView and you can see the issue

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to achieve that:

Insert a `SizedBox()` widget between every item

or

Change ListView widget to Column. Set the attribute `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`

Comment: Doesn't have the same behavior as a listview

Comment: I think it is not a good approach because  we have to again wrap with scroll widget